# win_ros Quaternion conversions

Tags: ros, quaternion, win-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm fairly new to ROS and i got stuck on the following problem. I have a setup where i have a node running on Ubuntu that controls a robot and reports its position. The position is encoded into Quaternion as follows:

```
tf::poseTFToMsg(tf::Transform(tf::createQuaternionFromYaw(theta), tf::Vector3(x, y, z)), position.pose.pose);
```

Now, i want to consume that information on windows. I've set it all up and everything works meaning that i receive the robot's position and all but win_ros doesn't seem to have tr:: package so i can't extract the 'theta' angle. Can anyone confirm that tr:: has not been ported to windows? And if so what's the proper way of extracting robot's orientation from Quaternion?

Edit:

I've done the conversion myself a while back but forgot to post it here. Even though it's pretty straight forward here is the code that works well for me (i just took it straight out of `tf::` code and massaged it a little).

```
static void convertQuaternion2Matrix(const geometry_msgs::Quaternion& q, double m[3][3])
{
    double d = q.x*q.x + q.y*q.y + q.z*q.z + q.w*q.w;
    if(d == 0.) 
        return;
    double s = 2./d;
    double xs = q.x * s,   ys = q.y * s,   zs = q.z * s;
    double wx = q.w * xs,  wy = q.w * ys,  wz = q.w * zs;
    double xx = q.x * xs,  xy = q.x * ys,  xz = q.x * zs;
    double yy = q.y * ys,  yz = q.y * zs,  zz = q.z * zs;
    //row1
    m[0][0] = 1.0 - (yy + zz);
    m[0][1] = xy - wz;
    m[0][2] = xz + wy;
    //row2
    m[1][0] = xy + wz;
    m[1][1] = 1.0 - (xx + zz);
    m[1][2] = yz - wx;
    //row3
    m[2][0] = xz - wy;
    m[2][1] = yz + wx;
    m[2][2] = 1.0 - (xx + yy);
}

static double tfAcos(double x) 
{ 
    if (x < -1.)
        x = -1.;
    if (x > 1.)
        x = 1.;
    return acos(x);
}

static double tfAsin(double x) 
{ 
    if (x < -1.)
        x = -1;
    if (x > 1)
        x = 1;
    return asin(x);
}

static void getEulerYPR(const geometry_msgs::Quaternion& q, double& yaw, double& pitch, double& roll, unsigned int solution_number = 1)
{
    double m[3][3];
    convertQuaternion2Matrix(q, m);
    struct Euler
    {
        double yaw;
        double pitch;
        double roll;
    };

    Euler euler_out;
    Euler euler_out2; //second solution
    //get the pointer to the raw data

    // Check that pitch is not at a singularity
    // Check that pitch is not at a singularity
    if (fabs(m[2][0]) >= 1)
    {
        euler_out.yaw = 0;
        euler_out2.yaw = 0;

        // From difference of angles formula
        double delta = atan2(m[2][1],m[2][2]);
        if (m[2][0] < 0)  //gimbal locked down
        {
            euler_out.pitch = M_PI / 2.0;
            euler_out2.pitch = M_PI / 2.0;
            euler_out.roll = delta;
            euler_out2.roll = delta;
        }
        else // gimbal locked up
        {
            euler_out.pitch = -M_PI / 2.0;
            euler_out2.pitch = -M_PI / 2.0;
            euler_out.roll = delta;
            euler_out2.roll = delta;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        euler_out.pitch = - tfAsin(m[2][0]);
        euler_out2.pitch = M_PI - euler_out.pitch;

        euler_out.roll = atan2(m[2][1]/cos(euler_out.pitch), 
            m[2][2]/cos(euler_out.pitch));
        euler_out2.roll = atan2(m[2][1]/cos(euler_out2.pitch), 
            m[2][2]/cos(euler_out2.pitch));

        euler_out.yaw = atan2(m[1][0]/cos(euler_out.pitch), 
            m[0][0]/cos(euler_out.pitch));
        euler_out2.yaw = atan2(m[1][0]/cos(euler_out2.pitch), 
            m[0][0]/cos(euler_out2.pitch));
    }

    if (solution_number == 1)
    { 
        yaw = euler_out.yaw; 
        pitch = euler_out.pitch;
        roll = euler_out.roll;
    }
    else
    { 
        yaw = euler_out2.yaw; 
        pitch = euler_out2.pitch;
        roll = euler_out2.roll;
    }
}

static double getYaw(const geometry_msgs::Quaternion& q)
{
    double r, p, y; 
    getEulerYPR(q, y, p, r);
    return y;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62483/win_ros-quaternion-conversions/) by [Eugene Simine](https://answers.ros.org/users/4860/eugene-simine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-06-14**:
That's useful to have floating around for people, thanks Eugene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the wiki, `tf` and `tf_conversion` packages are part of the [geometry](http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry) stack.  I don't know if the `win_ros` wiki is up-to-date, but its [supported stacks](http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/Msvc%20Status) list does not include the `geometry` stack.

As you've probably already seen, the "normal" way in ROS is to use the `tf::` functions:

```
tf::Matrix3x3(q).getRPY(R,P,Y)
```

But, if you can't build the `tf` package in win_ros, you can always copy-paste the math from the relevant tf functions:

1. build a rotation matrix from quaternion data (see [setRotation](http://ros.org/rosdoclite/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/Matrix3x3_8h_source.html#l00173))
2. convert rotation matrix to Euler Angles (see [getEulerYPR](http://ros.org/rosdoclite/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/Matrix3x3_8h_source.html#l00319))

Alternatively, you could use the transform functions built into [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org), which should be available on Windows.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1